# Using 'ng deploy' to Azure

Tags: angular, azure, deployment

I am trying to use a relatively new package to deploy to an Azure web site using the Angular CLI.

Here are the steps I used

1. ng add @azure/ng-deploy

I am prompted to login to my Azure account.

I end up with a message that I don't have any subscriptions. But I don't believe that because I have a subscription id and subscription name that I can view in the Azure portal

2. ng build --prod
3. ng deploy

*Rs-MacBook-Pro$ ng deploy
Your global Angular CLI version (8.3.4) is greater than your local
version (8.1.3). The local Angular CLI version is used.
To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
The specified command ("deploy") is invalid. For a list of available options,
run "ng help".
Did you mean "doc"?*

I think that one of the reasons that the deploy command is invalid is that the previous step of adding '@azure/ng-deploy' failed. So the question that I have is how to I point or configure the CLI deployment to use my existing Azure account?

Thank you.

Comment: did you find a fix for this?